# OpenGL ES 2.0 Z-Axis not effecting occlusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

So I am doing some OpenGL experimentation using this tutorial but I am running into an issue, for some reason the depth of my vertices doesn't seem to matter in how they are drawn. In the screenshot below the cubes have the same size, however the larger cube is closer to the screen. I believe it should be occluding the smaller cube, but it is not. I have followed the code in the tutorial almost exactly, is there anything obviously wrong?

http://games.ianterrell.com/opengl-basics-with-glkit-in-ios5-encapsulated-drawing-and-animation/

[screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2396540/image.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2396540/image.png)

Comment: I am using the same code from the link, I did not want to paste it all here since there is a lot to it, and i'm not exactly sure where i should be looking.

Comment: If theirs works and yours doesn't, then just find what's different. No one will do more than skim the entire tutorial for you in an attempt to locate something that might be an error, especially if it is not known whether there is an error or where this error may or may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably set up your GLKView without a depth buffer. GLKView has a propery `drawableDepthFormat` that controls creation and precision of the drawable's depth buffer. The default value is `GLKViewDrawableDepthFormatNone` which is good for 2D compositing.

When you want to draw 3D objects you should set it to `GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16` or `GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24` if you need more depth precision.

Comment: that looks right, i will be able to check after work. but I do not remember setting that. Thank you.